# Creating CampaignResponse in CRM 2013

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to create a CampaignResponse using late-bound method in Dynamics 2013.

I found this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959317.aspx but noticed that this is for Dynamics 4.0 and a lot of the Entity attribute types have changed. One example is that `campaignresponse`'s `ownerid` used to be a `Lookup` and I believe now is `EntityReference`.

I can't find updated information on Entities. How can I properly create a CampaignResponse using late-bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't so much different in creating `CampaignResponse` than another entity.

Late bound will be something similar to this example:

```
Entity campaignResponse = new Entity("campaignresponse");
campaignResponse["subject"] = "My Campaign Response"
campaignResponse["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("campaign", campaignId);
// other fields
service.Create(campaignResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I can find updated Entity information for 2013?

Comment: EntityMetadata.xlsx file inside the SDK